# Vue-tsc shows an error badge but reports 0 errors

Tags: typescript, nuxtjs3, vue-tsc

After upgrading from NUXT 3 Release candidate to the latest and released version and making the changes I needed in order to get everything running smoothly, vue-tsc has started showing an error-badge just before reporting 0 errors.

Do I actually have any errors, or is there something else going on here?

Is it vue-tsc logging the badge, or something else?

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rUlK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rUlK.png)]

**Versions**

- Nuxt: 3.2.2
- vue-tsc: 1.1.5
- typescript: 4.8.3

Going back to Nuxt 3.0.9-rc along with downgrading vue-tsc removes the "error".

Comment: Here is the [bug report](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/19145#issuecomment-1529135937) in nuxt repo. Developer claims that `npm upgrade vite-plugin-checker` is supposed to fix the issue, even though it did not for me =/

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with Nuxt 3.2.3 and vue-tsc 1.2.0. However, it raises only if I enable type check in development mode. I did this either by adding to `nuxt.config.json` the following option (like official Nuxt docs state here https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/typescript):

```
typescript: { typeCheck: true }
```

or with [vite-plugin-checker](https://vite-plugin-checker.netlify.app/checkers/overview.html) and

```
checker({ vueTsc: true })
```

for `vite.plugins` property.

In both cases an ugly red ERROR badge followed by 0 errors is still there.

I haven't found any solution so I've just removed this in-dev check from nuxt.config.json and rely on:

- my IDE which follows `tsconfig.json` rules anyways
- pre-commit hook with explicit linting commands (`eslint` and `nuxi typecheck` in my case, though it can be `vue-tsc --noEmit` as well).

This way I can be sure no errors go to the repo while developers are still notified about them when writing their code.

I know this isn't an answer to your question (and probably not the best solution...) but just wanted to give more context for those who could probably clarify this one.

Comment: Seems like this was reintroduced https://github.com/fi3ework/vite-plugin-checker/issues/238